# How to compare the code of two non-sequential commits in git?

Tags: git, github, diff

I'm pretty new to git and github. The github client lets me compare the differences in the code for two sequential commits. However, I am trying to compare the code changes of two non-sequential commits.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git diff sha1..sha2
```

This should do it.

Comment: `git diff sha1 sha2` would be better (without the `..` - using the range syntax may currently "work", but I know there have been discussions about whether it should, and what that should even mean).